# How to set variable as row number in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that inserts a row at the end of a section and and then copies formulas from above.

My only problem is that I am not sure how to define a variable such as "iRow" as a dynamic range.

The code below is the part that copies the formulas only from the row above. If I set iRow as a fixed number, the whole code works. However, I need the "iRow"-variable to take on whatever row number in which the value "2" can be found in column B.

I have tried things like Columns("B:B").Find(What:=2).

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Dim iRow As Integer
  iRow = ???
  'Select row
  Rows(iRow - 1).EntireRow.Copy
  'Paste it into the new row
  Rows(iRow).PasteSpecial

  Rows(iRow).SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: First of all, row variables should be `Long` and not `Integer` - secondly, based on the code you posted, iRow will be a value of `0` and then `iRow - 1` will be zero or negative, which will result in an error. To answer your question... `iRow = 2` instead of `???`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this is precisely what I need help with. I need the iRow variable to take on the number value of the row in which the value 2 can be found. In my file, the value 2 is for example found on row 64. However, if I insert a new row, the value 2 is now on row 65. If I again want to insert a new row and set iRow=64, the code will not work. Therefore, I need to have a dynamic variable that is always equal to the row number of "2".

Comment: Are you asking how to find the last row that contains data?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> "However, I need the "iRow"-variable to take on whatever row number in
>   which the value "2" can be found in column B."

You probably need something like:

```
Sub test()

Dim iRow as Long
With Sheet1 'Use an explicit sheet reference, use a sheets CodeName
    iRow = .Columns(2).Find(2, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    'Rest of code
End With

End Sub
```

This will get the row number of the first occurrence of 2. If no value of two is found this will yield an error though.

Comment: Post is downvoted but answers the question: `"However, I need the "iRow"-variable to take on whatever row number in which the value "2" can be found in column B."`. Please leave a comment on what the reason would be for a downvote so the post can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic row counter, you need a count. with the below code, if you set the column to B for example and use a counter, it will always look for the last row.

For Example

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim iRow As Integer
'This will give the last number in the row that is filled
iRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Select row
Rows(iRow - 1).EntireRow.Copy
'Paste it into the new row
Rows(iRow).PasteSpecial

 Rows(iRow).SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I would also declare the workbook and worksheet, but in this example, I left it out.

Comment: What if I want to look for the row containg a specific value in column B and not the last row?

Comment: Are you looking for when a specific value is found return the row number? As from what your code describes you want to remove everything

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this. I am looking to set iRow as the row number in which a certain value is found in column B. Once I've done this, I need the code to paste formulas from from the row above the row in which this specific value has been found. If that is even possible...? Maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong direction? The last part of my code is only removing any hardcoded values that has been filled down and keeps the formulas.